# Content-Lenght mismatch on Azure Storage while audio streaming

Tags: azure, streaming, azure-storage

On Azure Storage service, i do mp3 streaming by doing range requests. For that reason, i set DefaultServiceVersion as "2011-08-18" for unversioned requests. I am able to get range response information headers and jumping middle of the audio file on HTML 5 Audio player.

I experience that usually i can't play whole audio file because streaming stops suddenly somewhere in middle of the file. I watched request informations via Fiddler application and i see that Azure Storage does not send whole requested range because fiddler give warning.

> "Content-Length mismatch: Response Header indicated 6.318.692 bytes,
>   but server sent 2.007.994"

Also when i watch request in Chrome Developer Tools, the request is failing in somewhere of the file. This is quite frequently happen. Why request completed without getting full requested byte range ?

Answer (score 0):

Check that you're not seeing a timeout.  Quite often load balancing and similar features will terminate long duration connections.

Comment: I also suspect that this problem happens when streaming takes time to complete. How can i know that i get timeout issue ? I don't get such a error information in fiddler and browser. Also i know that Azure Storage is right service for such as tasks.

Comment: See if you can reproduce this at around the same time with the same file (or set of files that are around the same size).  Then try smaller files until you find one that always plays back fully.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend enabling logging on your account. (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/hh343270.aspx for more info on Logging / Metrics). This can be done easily via the azure portal. Once this is done you will have more information to self diagnose the issue from the service perspective.

Joe